# Permutation limits on resource-constrained host

Tags: python, algorithm, sed, shuffle

I have a large text file, about 8 GB, whose lines I need to shuffle randomly and uniformly. I cannot partition the text file and shuffle — shuffling must be done over the entire file.

I am running into limits where GNU `shuf` craps out on a resource-limited host (1 GB memory) and so I am exploring alternatives that deliberately stay within the scope of the abilities of this host.

One thought I had was to build a Python (2.7.5) list of digits from `[1..n]`, where `n` is the number of lines in this 8 GB file — about 25 millions lines — randomly permute the list, and iterate over the list to get the index (or line number) to feed to `sed -n <line_index>p`.

Are there limits to Python's ability to permute a list of 25M elements? Are there limits to `sed`s ability to efficiently pull out lines by index, where the indices are of that range?

Are there more efficient ways to shuffle lines of large text files on resource-constrained hosts?

Answer (score 3):

I think something like the following might might work.

```
from random import shuffle

# ... rest of the code ...

lnPos = [f.tell()]
for l in f.readlines(): lnPos.append( f.tell() )
shuffle( lnPos )

# Now open a file to write and write the lines
for pos in lnPos:
    f.seek(pos, 0)
    fOut.write( f.readline() )
```

I havent checked for syntax errors, but I think this might just work. Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: Basically, the idea is that it finds the location of the beginning of each line, and then shiffles that list of positions. The list of positions will hopefully be much smaller than the entire file.

Comment: Are you reading all the lines!? Be aware that the size of the entire file is 8 GB.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how lazy the `f.readlines()` function really is. I am not exactly sure how we can arrive at the list of positions of the beginning of the lines in the files without reading the lines either. Maybe there is a better/more efficient `find()` method which will do the same thing? The idea is to find the positions of the `\n`s in the file, and then using that information to shuffle the file.

Comment: You would have to read the file, to know the number of lines anyway.

Comment: The `shuffle` might have to be changed to `shuffle( lnPos[:-1] )` to remove the position of the `EOF`.

Comment: `readlines` creates a complete list of all the lines in the file. It's generally unnecessary; `for l in f` reads the lines in chunks instead of all at once, which is what you want here.

Comment: Disk performance is probably going to suck with all those random seeks, though.

Comment: I like this idea, along with user2357112's suggestion to buffer input.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & sort):

```
seq $(cat file | wc -l) | sort -R | sed 's|.*|sed -n '\''&{p;q}'\'' file|e' >output
```

Comment: Note that the result of `sort -R` is not a true random permutation.

Comment: @AlexReynolds you could substitute `shuf` for `sort -R` as you are only dealing with 25,000,000 integers.

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate through the lines of your file, you can write them randomly to one of 16 partitions. Then, shuffle each partition, and rejoin them afterwards.

Some (untested) code. The function takes file-like objects in_file and out_file, and the number of partitions to use.

```
def shuffle(in_file, out_file, n):
    out = [open('shard-%02d-of-%02d' % (i, n), 'w') for i in xrange(n)]
    for line in infile:
        out[random.randrange(n)].write(line)
    for o in out: o.close()
    for i in xrange(n):
        with open('shard-%02d-of-%02d' % (i, n), 'r') as part:
            lines = part.readlines()
        random.shuffle(lines)
        for x in lines:
            out_file.write(x)
```

Comment: I don't think this shuffles uniformly through the entire file.